# Create triggers related to variables

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, triggers

I have a class that looks like this:

```
Public Class LumberPiece
    Public boardLength As Double
    Public currentLeftEndPosition As Double
    Public currentRightEndPosition As Double

    Public Sub New(ByVal bl As Double, ByVal clp As Double)
        boardLength = clsDimension.ConvertInchesToMillimeters(bl)
        currentLeftEndPosition = clsDimension.ConvertInchesToMillimeters(clp)
        currentRightEndPosition = clsDimension.ConvertInchesToMillimeters(clp + bl)
    End Sub
End Class
```

I want to somehow have a trigger that calculates the currentRightEndPosition everytime that the currentLeftEndPosition is changed (rightEnd always equals leftend+ boardLength).

how can I do this?

Comment: I don't know the exact VB syntax, but what you're looking to do is replace those public variables with public *properties* that use *private* variables.  (This is a good practice in general, for exactly the issue in this question primarily.)  Inside of the property you can have business logic in response to setting (or even getting) the value.  The constructor would most likely still use the private variables directly, but any external access to the public properties would invoke the logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using properties.  By making the fields properties, you can control what happens when the property values are read and when they are set.  For instance:

```
Public Class LumberPiece
    Public Property BoardLength As Double

    Public Property CurrentLeftEndPosition As Double
        Get
            Return _currentLeftEndPosition
        End Get
        Set(value As Double)
            _currentLeftEndPosition = value
            CurrentRightEndPosition = clsDimension.ConvertInchesToMillimeters(_currentLeftEndPosition + BoardLength)
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _currentLeftEndPosition As Double

    Public Property CurrentRightEndPosition As Double

    Public Sub New(ByVal bl As Double, ByVal clp As Double)
        BoardLength = clsDimension.ConvertInchesToMillimeters(bl)
        CurrentLeftEndPosition = clsDimension.ConvertInchesToMillimeters(clp)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Alternatively, you could choose to calculate the field every time it is accessed:

```
Public Class LumberPiece
    Public Property BoardLength As Double
    Public Property CurrentLeftEndPosition As Double

    Public ReadOnly Property CurrentRightEndPosition As Double
        Get
            Return clsDimension.ConvertInchesToMillimeters(CurrentLeftEndPosition + BoardLength)
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New(ByVal bl As Double, ByVal clp As Double)
        BoardLength = clsDimension.ConvertInchesToMillimeters(bl)
        CurrentLeftEndPosition = clsDimension.ConvertInchesToMillimeters(clp)
    End Sub
End Class
```